# Create Spring MVC , ibatis project using Appfuse-

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, appfuse

can anyone give some references and help to do this?

Currently i am referncing this site  http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should go through the [Using iBATIS](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Using+iBATIS) section in [Tutorials](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Tutorials) -> [Persistence](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Persistence) section of [Appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) documentation.